Bring back tag wiki excerpts to tag pages
Thanks to some recent changes, tag wiki excerpts have been removed from the tag pages themselves.
Example from kotlin:






This change was previously limited to tag hover popups, but has now propagated to the tag pages themselves.
As I have previously mentioned, along with several other people (1 2 3 4) on the tag hover changes have pointed out, this makes it significantly harder for us to communicate what the tags are for. While it was one thing to change it in the hover popups, changing it on the tag page too means excerpt information is now hidden behind several clicks, and isn't displayed anywhere in top-level UI elements.
Please bring it back. This is an extremely negative change for all forms of tag curation.

So... effectively, instead of hearing feedback, they're moving forward with only providing tag guidance when adding new tags to a post, there's no way to access that guidance on an existing tag on a post without first removing it or going to the tag wiki page.

@KevinB Yep. Doesn't it feel great to be heard? /s

So, my experience today: I saw a question which talked about memory and was tagged [[tag:paging]]. I wondered whether the tag is about memory paging or separating data into pages (pagination/paging). I hovered over the tag - no information. I clicked on the tag - no information. I clicked "Go to Wiki" - two clicks, and two tabs later, finally saw the excerpt and found it's meaning 1 - memory paging.

I don't understand, isn't the excerpt still there at the top of the "tag wiki page" inside the box with a border?

It's on the tag wiki, yes, but it's not on the tag search result page that you get when you click on a tag.

It's still there for me using rev 2024.8.21.14283

To anyone confused, the content shown on the tag search page isn't consistent, for some tags it shows the content from the excerpt (potentially after truncating it) and for others it shows a truncated part of the tag wiki. For example for python the content comes from the wiki while for django it shows stuff from the excerpt. I guess it might have something to do with how the initial part of the wiki is formatted (Maybe if the initial part is not a plain paragraph they go with the excerpt)

@AbdulAzizBarkat Weird. I found a few excerpt-only tag wikis that showed nothing. Can't find the established-ish tag I saw previously, but [tag:openreview] shows this problem. Really inconsistent behaviour there

Maybe we should just copy all the excerpts as the first parts of the wikis so we have proper guidance again /s

@cafce25 You joke, but that's an actual plan that's actually on the table if it's confirmed that this change won't be reverted. I'll automate it, and it's doable in 5-10 days (possibly less with some quota magic), but it will result in an estimated 50000 fully avoidable edits. Also a completely pointless use of time, but if this is how SE intends tag wikis to work now, there are no alternatives.

@VLAZ clearly the clicks are there for accessiblility; more clicks more accessible. That's why visited links and text are both black here on SO Meta; it's more accessible if you can't tell if text is a link or not. :)

@ThomA SE Dictionary describes it as: accessibility (noun): quality or characteristic of something that means how much activity is needed to utilise it. The more you access it the more accessible it is. Example usages: "This information has good accessibility - I have to spend more time to obtain it because I had to keep accessing more and more pages." or "The tag excerpt had poor accessibility - you didn't have to invest any effort to find it."

Note that SE has formally been given a deadline of 2024-08-30 at 12:00 UTC to respond. After this, an automation effort to mass-edit tag wikis to restore the excerpt will start. The exact count of edits required at the time of writing is 46177, affecting 69.95% of tags, with an estimated 7-14 days to complete due to lacking API support for tag wiki edits and ✨ special requirements ✨ for running automation under mod accounts

Where is the meta announcement detailing this change? I would like to vote to express my (dis)agreement.

@CPlus I honestly don't know. I've been pointed to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/400648/332043, but this makes no mention of changes to the excerpt, at least on the tag pages. The update header currently on there (for future reference, added on August 22nd 2024) mentions that "[SE has]  released the simplified tag page header to Stack Overflow". I think that's about as close as you get

Forget moderator strikes: this is enough to make the rank and file strike, too.

Marking this one as status-completed as we continued our conversation around the tag hover here.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431716/dont-mark-feature-requests-that-were-not-addressed-as-completed

Ironically, you marked this as [status-completed] even though the tag excerpt of [status-completed] should remind you that the tag doesn't apply here. The excerpts reads: "It indicates that the report has been resolved through the implementation of a feature or the fixing of a bug." Did you folks restore tag wiki excerpts on the tag page? You didn't. Nothing is "completed" here. Also the feedback request post is hardly a continuation of this conversation. This post makes a specific request about an issue that needs to be specifically addressed, and not just with "we asked for feedback".
