Don't mark feature requests that were not addressed as completed
As many of us are aware, there was a lot of turmoil due to Tag hover experiment wrap-up and next steps. Multiple feature requests, discussions, bug reports, etc. were filed to reverse the changes and address the issues that were introduced by that.
SO recently posted a new question soliciting feedback on how we use tagged question page: Feedback Requested: How do you use the tagged questions page?. In favor of that question, the previous posts regarding the changes were tagged with status-completed. I am not sure if that's the right action; see the following questions:

Feedback for the "simplified tag page header"

Bring back tag wiki excerpts to tag pages


While I have suggested to tag them as status-deferred, I am more in favor of dan1st's suggestion: closing those questions as duplicate of the new one. Or even leave them as is with status-review. In any case, I am certain that marking them as completed is not the right course of action, considering that status-completed wiki/excerpt reads: " It indicates that the report has been resolved through the implementation of a feature or the fixing of a bug".
Is there something that I missed here, or the latest edits on both of the linked questions should be reverted?

I think we should be able to plainly look at the clarity the company's trying to bring to status tags to be able to determine whether this tagging is appropriate. From that post:




Status tag
What it expresses
When to use it
When not to use it




status-completed (any post type)
We have done all the work we intend to do
We took every action we intend to
An issue resolved without any action on our part




This usage doesn't seem to fit the "What it expresses" or "When to use it" categories at all. I don't think the two posts you referred to are in a state where SE has done all they intended to do. At the very least status-completed is inappropriately used here, and is inconsistent with the usage guidance that was proposed just a bit over a month ago.
I'm not going to prescribe a solution here (the one in your OP is fine), but I'd like to point out that we're already not correctly using the guidance SE has proposed that was meant to bring clarity to these tags.
This is in no way personal towards SpencerG; he's clearly trying to be helpful and indicate the next steps for these posts, and I really think we should encourage transparency and communication from the company to the community. I just think it's really important we're all on the same page with how/when to use these tags as their conveyed meaning is impactful on company <-> community communication.

I want to reiterate your point about this not being personal. I, too, believe the intentions are genuine.

Yes, questions requesting feedback where the window for feedback has closed should be closed in order to prevent additional answers. Ideally, they'd be closed as duplicates of the more current discussion. But if that doesn't exist or isn't appropriate, then they should be closed as obsolete. This is a very special case; normally [status-*] tags should be used instead of closure because we do not want to prevent answering. But if the answers are not going to be looked at, and it is preferred that a new question be created for feedback, then closing to prevent answers is precisely appropriate.

Closing a [status-*] question as a duplicate without or instead of adding a new [status-*] tag causes its own problems, given that closure can be reversed by the community whereas red [status-*] tags cannot. See for example this MSE post where a staff member attempted to do exactly that, the community reversed the decision, and basically all status information was lost. Since comments are ephemeral, I quote here the exchange I had there:


Removing status tags without actually adding a resolution breaks trust in the entire process of escalating things for review in the first place. As it is right now, it looks like you just gave up and can't be bothered to review it anymore: If the feature request is declined, just use [status-declined]. — goldPseudo
we are doing some housekeeping. It didn't feel right to status-decline the post, as we added similar messaging to the current CoC. So, after some thinking, I closed it as 'non-repo', as seemed like the best option, being there is an entirely new CoC from when the request was made. I did leave a comment stating that so I am unsure what you mean by 'just closing without adding a resolution'. — Bella_Blue
I didn't mention closing: Closure is a completely different tool (one which was almost immediately undone by the community) and should not be a replacement for proper tagging. You removed a status tag, and didn't replace it with a new status tag. That puts this "feature request" back into limbo, instead of resolving anything. If you do think "norepro" is the appropriate response, then use [status-norepro]. If you contend that the new COC did resolve this, then [status-completed]. — goldPseudo
in the post history, the only recorded reason for your closure is "Not suitable for this site" which I doubt is what you intended at all, and comes off as incredibly dismissive for a feature request with this much support. And posting an actual answer explaining your reasoning would be far more visible than posting a single link without context, which is now buried in the middle of a lengthy comment thread. — goldPseudo
"in the post history, the only recorded reason for your closure is "Not suitable for this site" which I doubt is what you intended at all, and comes off as incredibly dismissive for a feature request with this much support." I was unaware it only recorded that. That is frustrating and I understand what the perception was, and I appreciate you understood that was not my intent. These other tag suggestions do seem like better options. I am thinking about which is most suitable, thank you :) — Bella_Blue


It also causes difficulties when there's cross-network feature requests, since one can't close as duplicate a feature request made on a per-site meta when the conversation is moved over to a network-wide meta.
TL;DR, closing and tagging are two completely different tools, comments are ephemeral, and none of these should be used as a replacement for each other. A proper solution consists of using the available tools appropriately.
That all said, introduction of a red [status-duplicate] or [status-obsolete] tag might be valuable.

Thank you, this is valuable history. So much so, that I think you may want to post something to MSE and expand on your tl;dr. Cheers.

One thing that I'd want to mention is that closing as a dupe and other closure reasons are different. You do touch on that, but maybe not as clearly that I'd like :) While closing a feature request which is under review does not replace usage of status tags, closing them as dupes does not raise as much problems.

@M-- I don't want to come off as saying that closing is bad; closing for any reason can shut down the discussion, which is appropriate, but that doesn't permanently capture the most important information of "we're not paying attention to this; go over there to discuss this further". Whether closed as a duplicate or not, It still has the same basic problem in that if the post is re-opened, one needs to dig through the history to uncover the relevant context, and most people will not do that.

Sigh, you already covered this when you said "A proper solution consists of using the available tools appropriately." That goes for the privileged community members who abused their reopen-vote privileges. Raise a flag on it; let a moderator handle it. Or, we can just apply a lock on the question (historical or obsolete). That people will do stupid things and misuse the tools does not justify us misusing the tools and applying status tags. [status-duplicate] is the close-as-duplicate feature. [status-obsolete] is the obsolete lock. Tagging is inappropriate here.

@CodyGray That implies that the community should no longer have any opinion on whether something is a duplicate or not. Just because a staff member unilaterally decrees that a feature request is covered elsewhere doesn't mean that the community needs to agree; if enough people feel that it still covers different ground and choose not to abandon it, or to continue discussing the issue, that's hardly an abuse of tools. Just because staff no longer chooses to follow the discussion doesn't mean that further discussion isn't warranted, or that it doesn't have value.

Tags are used to categorize and organize information, closure is used to control interactions on a post. Staff has been using [status-*] tags to categorize how the item is (or was) being tracked internally, which is completely tangential to whether anyone is interacting with the post or not.

If the discussion has moved elsewhere and is not going to be seen on the old question, then closing it as a duplicate makes perfect sense and is completely appropriate. Reopening it is not appropriate, because it's sending the wrong signal. Yes, the community also has the privileges to close staff announcements that they don't like, and even vote to delete them. But we strongly encourage people not to do that, and we take action to prevent it from actually happening. It's not as if this is foreclosing the community's ability to discuss things. They can just ask a new question.

I mean, that's exactly the point here, though, right? Closure is used to control interactions on a post. This is what we seek to do. And the tags being applied here are not categorizing or organizing anything. Nor are they consistent with the tagging system long-followed and recently-documented by staff. The evidence all suggests that tagging is the wrong tool for the job. Your major argument against it is that staff or mod privileges are required to mess with the tags, and I'm saying that's not a compelling enough argument to justify using the wrong tool for the job.
